# Nodejs Encryption and Decryption

Tags: node.js, encryption

I am stuck in node js **node-rsa** library. I have implemented this library properly, but the problem I am facing is it is taking quite a lot time for performing decryption. So due to that my node API is failing in performance testing.

So I am need of help for any reliable solution which helps in clearing the stage of performance testing. Please do provide an example in solution.

Comment: Why are you not using bcrypt js

Comment: Post your source code if you want help.

Comment: @shankarsingh bcrypt and RSA solve completely different problems...  They aren't even slightly similar.

Comment: I need something similar to RSA

Comment: RSA decryption indeed takes a lot of time, it is very compute intensive (regardless used technology). You could post your source code to see if someone could help optimizing it. If it is API, I hope you are not blocking whole server thread just for decryption